# Symfony crontab issue

Tags: php, symfony, cron, command

I'm developing a Symfony project (Symfony 4) and I've a command which allows me to send an email. When I use my terminal on local ( `php bin/console app:end-training-email` ) the command works fine.
Now, I want to put this command in crontab on a OVH VPS .
My command also works when I use the the terminal on the VPS.

When I try to put this

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/bin/console app:end-training-email >> /tmp/log7.cron
```

in `/etc/crontab` file I got nothing in it. However when I put the same line but with

`cache:clear` command, it works.

Here is my command method in Symfony :

```
<?php
namespace App\Command;
use App\Repository\CustomerRepository;
use App\Service\Mailer;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
/**
* Class EndTrainingEmailCommand
* @package App\Command
*/
class EndTrainingEmailCommand extends Command
{
protected static $defaultName = 'app:end-training-email';
private $customerRepository;
/**
* @var Mailer
*/
private $mailer;
public function __construct(CustomerRepository $customerRepository, Mailer $mailer)
{
$this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
$this->mailer = $mailer;
parent::__construct(null);
}
protected function configure()
{
$this
->setDescription('Send an email at the end of the training')
;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
$io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
$customers = $this->customerRepository->findAllTerminatedTraining();
if (!$customers) {
$io->error('No customers found !');
} else {
$io->success('Emails of end training were sent to customers !');
}
$io->progressStart(count($customers));
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
$io->progressAdvance();
$from = 'wild.developers.team@gmail.comnt';
$to = $customer->getEmail();
$viewCustomer = 'email/command/endTraining.html.twig';
$subjectCustomer = 'You enjoyed your last training? Let us know!';
$this->mailer->sendContactEmail($from, $to, $customer, $subjectCustomer,
$viewCustomer);
}
$io->progressFinish();
return 0;
}
}
```

I don’t understand why it doesn’t work with my command while it works with cache:clear
Thanks a lot for yours answers !

Comment: Are there any entries in the log, both your app's logs or your crontab logs (syslog)?

Comment: @dbrumann thx, you were right, app logs showed me that I've environment variables issues